# Expand/Collapse a WPF expander inside Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

How to expand/collapse expander inside listbox datatemplate using c# code.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Your one single run-on sentence is difficult to read. You are more likely to get help if you revise your post to make your thoughts clearer. Someone (like me) will edit and correct your English for you, but we can only do that if we can understand what you mean.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove: I want first expander controll get expanded in that listbox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask